# C++ coded DLL returning #VALUE! on Excel

Tags: c++, excel, dll

I coded a super simple formula on C++.

```
Double __stdcall test(double x)
{
Return x+1;
}
```

Then I made the Definition File, built the DLL and did the VBA Declare PtrSafe Function test Lib "folder\file.dll" (ByRef x As Double) As Double

The Excel seems to recognize the new function “test” but it returns #VALUE!

Some notes: I’m running a 64 bit Excel and built the 64 bit dll. Even tried to use a VBA function to call de DLL function, but it didn’t work as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is ByVal x As Double

Comment: Hey, Hans! Thanks for your reply. I actually tried both but they return #VALUE!